# Can't import javax.imageio.ImageIO in Android application

Tags: android, image-processing, javax.imageio

I want to save canvas object as image, and for this I want use ImageIO class. I'm using Eclipse, but when I try make import of this lib (import javax.imageio.ImageIO;) Eclipse is shows me an error "The import javax.imageio cannot be resolved". Pls. tell me what I have to do to solve this problem and import imageio lib to my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have tagged your question with Android. `javax.imageio.ImageIO` is not part of the Android platform, so unfortunately you can't use it. Instead, you need to use what's available in the Android SDK for reading and storing images.

Have a look at the [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) classes for a starting point.

These classes contain the necessary methods to read (`BitmapFactory.decode*(...)` methods) and write (`Bitmap.compress(...)` method).

Comment: What is javax.imageio "part" of? An android application is a java application with the Android framework. Isn't javax.imageio a library built into the jdk?

Comment: @JohnSardinha While the Android SDK and the JDK does share a lot of API, they are not the same. The javax.imageio package is part of the java.desktop module (from Java 9) and is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Its difficult to use Bitmap for gif and animated webp resizing. ImageIO is high level