# How can i download some image libraries to android?

Tags: android, awt, javax.imageio

What i want to do is to read some image in android and convert each pixel in my image to RGB values , and here is the code that i have found :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button test=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\images\\Sunset.jpg"));
                int[] pixel;

                for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
                        pixel = bi.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[3]);
                        System.out.println(pixel[0] + " - " + pixel[1] + " - " + pixel[2] + " - " + (bi.getWidth() * y + x));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But i have problems in importing some packages like this :

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

And i don't know how to download them or which is the best way to resolve this problem.. Any help??

Comment: you should use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
selected_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't load javax.imageio.ImageIO lib to Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693011/cant-load-javax-imageio-imageio-lib-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first one create Bitmap from File.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

next you can getPixel() from you bitmap

```
for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        android.util.Log.v("TAG", bitmap.getPixel(x,y));
    }
}
```

Comment: but how should i configure photopath?

Comment: photoPath is a String, the same as filePath in my answer. Also please note that is more efficient to read all the pixels at once with readPixels as in my example.

Comment: String photopath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "your_photo.jpg";

Comment: ok but i want to run it on emulator and my image is exist in C drive like this : C:\\images\\download.jpg , will it work? @user2038145

Comment: this will help you http://www.androiddevelopment.org/2008/11/11/how-to-create-and-use-the-sd-card-with-the-android-emulator/

Comment: well i am not trying to read it from sd card .. i want to read it from C drive on my computer , will it work?

Comment: no, emulator can access only its own sdcard. so you must create it first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60771/discussion-between-sereen-and-user2038145).

Comment: Use adb push or DDMS in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage or ImageIO are not available on android.

Instead of BufferedImage use [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), take a look at the getPixels function.

Instead of ImageIO use [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html), the function you need is decodeFile

---

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opts);

int pixels[] = new int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];

bitmap.getPixels(pixels,0,0,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
```