# Android app development, can't import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

Tags: android, eclipse, javax.imageio

I'm using Eclipse for android app development, but when I try make import of this lib `import javax.imageio.ImageIO;` Eclipse is shows me an error

> "The import javax.imageio cannot be resolved"

. Pls. tell me what I have to do to solve this problem and import imageio lib to my project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693011/cant-load-javax-imageio-imageio-lib-to-eclipse

Comment: Please check above link .Its a duplicate

Comment: But no body show the solution, so...