# Failed resolution of: Ljavax/imageio/stream/FileImageInputStream when using Java library

Tags: java, android, pixelmed

I'm trying to make an app which creates a DICOM file. There is a java library called PixelMed. I tried to use it in my Android project but when accessing methods from the library I get

```
Failed resolution of: Ljavax/imageio/stream/FileImageInputStream
```

From what I found I get this because javax is not a part of Android SDK. My question is: Is there a way to somehow import this library or make the PixelMed work on Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any library that uses `javax.imageio` with no possibility of working around it is not going to work on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693011/cant-import-javax-imageio-imageio-in-android-application

Comment: So there is no way that the PixelMed library will work on Android right? No possibility of import it somehow or anything?

Comment: I don't know those details. If there's a pluggable that allows it to use different API (or android-specific version), then it may work. If not, then no. As I already said.

Answer (score 1):

I it not possible to use PixelMed.jar file in Android, because javax/imageio is not supported in Android, the reason is that it is in java part not android, thats why it is not suppported, I also face that kind of error. I research the problem. I recommend to use other libraries like dicomhero or imebra libraries.